# Putting different buttons and dropdowns inline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a website that looks like MS Office Word. There should be some buttons (italics, bold, etc.) and two dropdowns (size and fonts). The problem for now is that no matter what I do, "size" cannot be shown next to "fonts". Because of the elements in the font dropdown, it comes after them. When I add `<br>` after the fonts, it's clear why "size" is under "fonts". However, when I remove`<br>`, there's a styling problem and there's a space between the last and the previous font, and "size" is only next to the fonts when I hover over the "font" button.
Here are some images to be more clear: 
with `<br>` while not hovering [image: with <code><br></code> while not hovering]
 
with `<br>` while hovering [image: with <code><br></code> while hovering]
without `<br>` while not hovering [image: without <code><br></code> while not hovering]
without `<br>` while hovering [image: without <code><br></code> while hovering] (the space really disturbs me because it disrupts the *hover* function)
So here's my code: html

```
<span id="toolbar">
 <button class="fontweight" onclick="bold()"><b>B</b></button>
 <button class="fontweight" onclick="italic()"><i>I</i></button>
 <button class="fontweight" onclick="underline()"><u>U</u></button>
 <span class="dropdownfonts" onmouseover="drop()" onmouseout="hide()" >
    <button id="dropdown" onmouseover="drop()" >Fonts</button><br>
    <span id="fonts">
    <button class="fonts"  onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Arial</button><br>
    <button class="fonts"  onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Calibri</button><br>
    <button class="fonts"  onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Century Gothic</button><br>
    <button class="fonts"  onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Comic Sans</button><br>
    <button class="fonts"  onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Consolas</button><br>
    <button class="fonts"  onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Courier</button><br>
    <button class="fonts"  onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">MV Boli</button><br>
    <button class="fonts"  onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Times New Roman</button>
    </span> 
 </span>
 <span class="dropdownfonts" onmouseover="dropsize()" onmouseout="hidesize()" >
    <button id="size">Size</button><br>
    <span id="sizes">
    <button class="sizes"  onclick="changesize(this.innerHTML)">10</button><br>
    <button class="sizes"  onclick="changesize(this.innerHTML)">12</button><br>
    <button class="sizes"  onclick="changesize(this.innerHTML)">14</button><br>
    <button class="sizes"  onclick="changesize(this.innerHTML)">16</button><br>
    <button class="sizes"  onclick="changesize(this.innerHTML)">18</button><br>
    <button class="sizes"  onclick="changesize(this.innerHTML)">20</button><br>
    <button class="sizes"  onclick="changesize(this.innerHTML)">22</button><br>
    <button class="sizes"  onclick="changesize(this.innerHTML)">24</button><br>
    </span>
    </span>
```

CSS:

```
.fonts {display: none;
position: relative;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
min-width: 300px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}
.sizes{display: none;
position: relative;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
min-width: 72px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}

#dropdown, #size,  .fontweight{
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: green solid 5px;
display: inline-block;
}


#fonts, #sizes{ 
display: inline;
position: relative;
}
#dropdownfonts{position: relative;
display: inline-block;  
}
#dropdown:hover, #dropdown:focus {
background-color: #2980B9;
}
```

JS:
    function bold(){ 
    document.getElementById("p").style.fontWeight="bold";

```
}

function underline(){

document.getElementById("p").style.textDecoration="underline"
            }

function italic(){

document.getElementById("p").style.fontStyle="italic";
}

function show(){
document.getElementById("p").style.display="block";
}

T=document.getElementsByClassName("fonts")

function hide()
{   for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)
T[i].style.display="none"; }

function drop()
{for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)
T[i].style.display="inline-block";}

S=document.getElementsByClassName("sizes")

function hidesize()
{   for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)
S[i].style.display="none"; }

function dropsize()
{for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)
S[i].style.display="inline-block";}

function change(btn)
{A=btn
document.getElementById("p").style.fontFamily=A;}


function changesize(button)
{B=button
document.getElementById("p").style.fontSize=B +  "px";}
```

And that's pretty much it! While I'm at it, is there any way to hide the space that the dropdown is taking? I think that that might actually be a solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the span #fonts absolute so it would be positioned to the closest relative and won't impact the flow.

```
.dropdownfonts {
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
}
#fonts {
display:block;
position:absolute;
}
```